# Envio de email con PHP (se envían datos anteriores)

Tags: php, angularjs, email

Tengo este problema que no eh entendido por que esta sucediendo
cuando envió un email desde **PHP** se envían los datos del email anterior, es decir, el primer email se envía en blanco y el segundo envía los datos del primero, dando como resultado un desfase de correos.

Los valores de `$input` y `$bol2` son los del desfase.

Adjunto código php:

```
 $data = file_get_contents("php://input");
       $postData = json_decode($data);
       $input = $postData->correo;
       $bol2 = $postData->bol;

$para = "destinatario";
        $asunto = 'Nueva Consulta de BL';
        $mensaje = "Correo: $input BL: $bol2";
        $cabeceras = 'From: someone@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: someone@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

        if(mail($para, $asunto, $mensaje, $cabeceras)) {
        echo 'Correo enviado correctamente';
        } else {
        echo 'Error al enviar mensaje';
        }
```

Tambien adjunto el codigo de angular que envia los datos a php

```
var bol2 = document.getElementById("txt").value;
var email= document.getElementById("email").value;

 $scope.SendData = function () {

        var data ={
            correo: email,
            bol: bol2
        };

        var config = {
            headers : {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'
            }
        }

        $http.post('email.php', data, config)
        .then(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.PostDataResponse = data;
        })

    };
}
```

Comment: ¿el primer correo enviado está completamente vacío, sin asunto, cuerpo ni destinatario?

Comment: bueno olvide especificar, solo las variables $input y $bol2 son las que llegan vacias en el primer correo

Comment: José, edita tu pregunta, los comentarios son temporales. Gracias.

Comment: Gracias por el aviso

Comment: José, puedes revisar [qué funciones tiene el sitio para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tu pregunta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). He editado tu pregunta, si tienes mas información que añadir, recuerda hacerlo editando tu pregunta. [edit]. Saludos.

Comment: Hola josé, necesitamos mas datos para poder responderte. el problema está en el js ya que estas usando dos variables aparentemente globales al controller: email y bol2. necesitamos saber Como se llenan estas variables: vienen de un model? de otra pagina? de un ajax?

Comment: @GerardoRosciano estan fuera del modulo de angular las trae desde html input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

José, lo primero que intentamos hacer al empezar a usar angular es mezclar js comun, jquery y angular, también queremos (o por lo menos yo al principio) modificar la dom desde los controllers. Pero angular te obliga a pensar el problema desde otra optica. Tu problema aquí es que estas obteniendo los datos antes de llenarlos. el js corre, las variables se llenan con el contenido de los inputs cuando se carga la pagina (es decir vacio) y luego, cuando se ejecuta el codigo de envio, las variables YA tienen el valor vacio.

solucionar el problema es relativamente facil, pero tenes que pensarlo de otra forma:

```
Debug: {{ email }} | {{ bol2 }}
<input type="text" id="email" ng-model="email" />
<input type="text" id="txt" ng-model="bol2" />
```

Ahora estas usando una de las caracteristicas mas atractivas de angular: 2-way binding, cada vez que escribas algo en el input, las variables van a cambiar inmediatamente. ahora en el controller:

```
$scope.SendData = function () {

    var data ={
        correo: $scope.email,
        bol: $scope.bol2
    };

    var config = {
        headers : {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'
        }
    }

    $http.post('email.php', data, config)
    .then(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.PostDataResponse = data;
    })

};
}
```

Si querés te puedo recomendar un par de libros que me sirvieron mucho cuando estaba aprendiendo

Comment: Gracias! Lo arreglo perfecto y claro me vendrían bien algunos libros saludos o/

Comment: @EduardoMendezOrtiz este curso me sirvió mucho: https://www.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angularjs Despues ojeá https://www.ng-book.com/ . Hay muy buenos tutoriales en Udemy tambien.